# The 'compilation' argument must be an instance of Compilation error in office add-in

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, office-addins, webpack-4

I am newbie to office add-in development but got one project in our organization. After installing all the dependencies mentioned in package.json file, when I am trying to run 'npm run dev-server', getting below error:

```
c:\git\sample-project\ui-addin>npm run dev-server

> ui-addin@1.0.0 dev-server c:\git\sample-project\ui-addin
> webpack-dev-server --mode development

You already have trusted access to https://localhost.
Certificate: C:\Users\Manish.Kumar\.office-addin-dev-certs\localhost.crt
Key: C:\Users\Manish.Kumar\.office-addin-dev-certs\localhost.key
i ｢wds｣: Project is running at https://127.0.0.1:3000/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from c:\git\sample-project\ui-addin
(node:19272) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: The 'compilation' argument must be an instance of Compilation
at Function.getCompilationHooks (c:\git\sample-project\ui-addin\node_modules\custom-functions-metadata-plugin\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:207:10)
at c:\git\sample-project\ui-addin\node_modules\custom-functions-metadata-plugin\lib\customfunctionsplugin.js:41:36
at SyncHook.eval [as call] (eval at create (c:\git\sample-project\ui-addin\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:7:1)
at SyncHook.lazyCompileHook (c:\git\sample-project\ui-addin\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
at Compiler.newCompilation (c:\git\sample-project\ui-addin\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:631:26)
at c:\git\sample-project\ui-addin\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:667:29
at eval (eval at create (c:\git\sample-project\ui-addin\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:14:1)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:19272) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:19272) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I verified the webpack version installed using 'npm ls webpack' and make it identical. But no luck yet. This same application is working file on another user's machine and he is able to run the add-in but I don't know why I am getting this error.

My package.json file:

```
{
"name": "ui-addin",
"version": "1.0.0",
"license": "MIT",
"config": {
    "app-to-debug": "excel",
    "app-type-to-debug": "desktop",
    "dev-server-port": 3000,
    "source-bundle-url-path": "index.win32"
},
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack -p --mode production --https false",
    "build:dev": "webpack --mode development --https false",
    "dev-server": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
    "lint": "office-addin-lint check",
    "lint:fix": "office-addin-lint fix",
    "prettier": "office-addin-lint prettier",
    "start": "office-addin-debugging start manifest-local.xml",
    "start:desktop": "office-addin-dev-settings webview manifest-local-sr.xml edge && office-addin-debugging start manifest-local-sr.xml desktop",
    "start:desktop-ie-webview": "office-addin-dev-settings webview manifest-local.xml edge && office-addin-debugging start manifest-local.xml desktop",
    "start:no-shared-runtime:desktop": "office-addin-debugging start manifest-local.xml desktop",
    "start:ci:desktop": "office-addin-debugging start manifest-ci.xml desktop",
    "sideload-local": "office-toolbox sideload -m manifest-local.xml -a Excel",
    "start:web": "office-addin-debugging start manifest-local.xml web",
    "stop": "office-addin-debugging stop manifest-local.xml",
    "stop:ci": "office-addin-debugging stop manifest-ci.xml",
    "validate": "office-addin-manifest validate manifest-local-sr.xml",
    "watch": "webpack --mode development --watch",
    "test": "mocha -r ts-node/register test/*.ts",
    "clear-all-cached-plugin": "rimraf \"%LOCALAPPDATA%\\Microsoft\\Office\\16.0\\Wef\""
},
"dependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "~3.5.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.10.3",
    "@babel/polyfill": "~7.10.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "~7.10.3",
    "@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli-ihsmarkit": "~4.3.4",
    "@types/custom-functions-runtime": "~1.5.1",
    "@types/find-process": "~1.2.0",
    "@types/mocha": "~7.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~14.0.14",
    "@types/office-js": "~1.0.111",
    "@types/office-runtime": "~1.0.14",
    "babel-loader": "~8.0.6",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "~3.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "~5.1.1",
    "custom-functions-metadata-plugin": "~1.0.30",
    "eslint-config-office-addins": "~1.0.15",
    "file-loader": "~4.2.0",
    "html-loader": "~0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "~3.2.0",
    "merge-jsons-webpack-plugin": "~1.0.21",
    "mocha": "~8.0.1",
    "office-addin-cli": "~1.0.10",
    "office-addin-debugging": "~3.0.31",
    "office-addin-dev-certs": "~1.5.2",
    "office-addin-dev-settings": "~1.8.3",
    "office-addin-lint": "~1.0.23",
    "office-addin-manifest": "~1.5.4",
    "office-addin-prettier-config": "~1.0.12",
    "office-addin-test-helpers": "~1.0.20",
    "office-addin-test-server": "~1.0.27",
    "prettier": "~1.19.1",
    "rimraf": "~3.0.2",
    "source-map-loader": "~0.2.4",
    "ts-loader": "~6.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.10.2",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5",
    "webpack": "~4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "~3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "~3.11.0"
},
"prettier": "office-addin-prettier-config"
```

}

Answer (score 6):

The problem is a quirk with Windows, Powershell, and how case sensitivity is handled.  I know that you used Powershell because this issue doesn't exist if you simply opened a command prompt.  (This may partially explain why it works on your colleague's workstation.)

TLDR; use command prompt or find the exact case of the directory (using Explorer for example) and use that case in Powershell.

The path you show above is:  `c:\git\sample-project\ui-addin`.

As a demonstration, I will create the same directory as you locally in a command prompt:

```
C:\>mkdir git\sample-project\ui-addin
C:\>cd git\sample-project\ui-addin
C:\git\sample-project\ui-addin>
```

Let's go to the same directory in Powershell:

```
PS C:\> cd Git\Sample-Project\Ui-ADDIN\
PS C:\Git\Sample-Project\Ui-ADDIN>
```

Huh?  Powershell will literally honor ANY case I use but also maintain it!  I didn't dig far enough into this issue to truly understand what is happening under the hood, but whatever it is it's enough for npm and Webpack to have issues.

For what it's worth, command shell won't honor any case other than the original:

```
C:\>cd Git\Sample-PROJECT\UI-addin\
C:\git\sample-project\ui-addin>
```

While many resources helped me resolve this issue, [this Github issue](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin/issues/466) helped me understand it and resolve it.

Comment: Thanks! But I am getting the same issue in command prompt also, and my colleague is using PowerShell where he is able to run this without any issue. So I don't think this is related to PowerShell or Command Prompt. As you mentioned I also verified the naming case of folders, but they are same, so again this is not something related to case.

Comment: Wow, that's really surprising.  I can consistently reproduce the identical error using the steps I outlined above.  In fact, I accidentally did it to myself just now doing development and trying to `npm run build` in Powershell with the wrong case.  Good luck!